# iTunes Documents Directory in my app

Tags: iphone, itunes, documents

how can I setup my app to accept documents via iTunes, like the Air Sharing or VLC app?
I mean, I want to allow users to get content from the app using iTunes.
Anyone know how?

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Copied from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS3_2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009337-SW11.

To enable file sharing for your application, do the following:

1. Add the UIFileSharingEnabled key to your application’s Info.plist file and set the value of the key to YES.
2. Put whatever files you want to share in your application’s Documents directory.
3. When the device is plugged into the user’s computer, iTunes displays a File Sharing section in the Apps tab of the selected device.
4. The user can add files to this directory or move files to the desktop.

Comment: is it possible to add folder in documents directory of the app from PC ?

Comment: In Xcode's 'friendly' key names: UIFileSharingEnabled is "Application supports iTunes file sharing"