# Using iPhone USB tethering connection from app

Tags: ios, usb, tethering

My app needs to transfer data to and from a PC/Mac, but without using Wireless or 3G.
Is it possible to use the USB cable to run a server on the device accessible by the PC/Mac?

Accessing the app's documents-directory over USB from a program would work too.

What would be the best way? I need a solution, that will work on normal device, no jailbreak allowed. If it works without special drivers on the PC/Mac, that's a bonus too.

Comment: If you just want to share files between computer and iPhone, you could use iTunes FileSharing.

Comment: Seems interesting, will try this! Is it possible to access this folder from a desktop program? There will be a lot of files and making the user click everything in iTunes does not seem acceptable atm. i would still prefer a real communication between desktop program and app to have full control what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable `UIFileShareEnabled`. More information is available here:

[iTunes Documents Directory in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818213/itunes-documents-directory-in-my-app)